# After quitting or stopping servers in MAMP, there is an error "httpd quit unexpectedly"

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, httpd.conf, osx-yosemite

The error only happens on my iMac not my Macbook Pro. All latest updates installed as of today.If I switch the apache port to 80 then no error but I have to enter my password every time I start MAMP. I might have messed with the apache settings in the past, but that was before I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: I also experience this issue on my iMac running Yosemite and the latest version of MAMP. Have you found a fix for that?

Comment: I somehow fixed it by uninstalling and then reinstalling Yosemite.